# How to nicely handle checked exceptions in constructors with Guice?

Tags: java, guice

I have code that reads like this:

```
class A {
  X x;

  A() {
    Class<? extends X> cls = ...;
    Module module = ...;
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
    x = injector.getInstance(cls);
  }
}
```

The concrete type `cls` is determined only at runtime and not known before this constructor is called.

My problem now is that the constructors of `cls` are expected to throw checked exceptions, and I'd like to handle them (if possible without unwrapping them from a ProvisionException). The Guice documentation says I should use the throwing providers extension, which seems to be complex here. Is there a simpler way than this:

```
interface MyCheckedProvider<T> extends CheckedProvider<T> {
  T get() throws MyCheckedException;
}

class XImplProvider implements MyCheckedProvider<X> {
  @Inject dependency1;
  @Inject dependency1;

  X get() throws MyCheckedException {
    return new XImpl(dependency1, dependency2);
  }
}

class ProviderHolder {
  @Inject MyCheckedProvider<X> provider;
}

class A {
  X x;

  A() {
    Class<? extends MyCheckedProvider<X>> providerClass = ...;
    Module module = new AbstractModule() {
      void configure() {
        ...
        ThrowingProviderBinder.create(binder())
          .bind(MyCheckedProvider.class, X.class)
          .to(providerClass.class);
      }
    };

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
    ProviderHolder holder = injector.getInstance(ProviderHolder.class);
    try {
      x = holder.provider.get();
    catch (MyCheckedException e) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The interface `MyCheckedProvider` would be ok, because it would be reusable in several places, but I'd need a separate `ProviderHolder` class at each place where something similar is needed, and I need a specific provider implementation for each class implementing X (of which there could be many). So this is even more work than just injecting an XFactory and writing an XFactoryImpl for each concrete type (which I tried to avoid).

I had hoped that I can do something like

```
injector.getInstance(new TypeLiteral<MyCheckedProvider<X>>() {});
```

or

```
injector.getCheckedProvider(cls, MyCheckedException.class);
```

but it seems this is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `Key` class here, not `TypeLiteral`.  Then there is no need for `ProviderHolder`:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
MyCheckedProvider<X> provider = injector.getInstance(new Key<MyCheckedProvider<X>>(){});
try {...
```

Comment: Of course, don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks! Now if I could get rid of `XImplProvider`, too, this would be great.